# two or more magento2 installation is possible or not in a single linux system?

Tags: magento2

I already successfully installed magento2 in locally ubuntu 14.04 LTS system. I need try to installation test another magento2-package So two or more magento2 installation is possible or not  in a single system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can install as many instances until your resource allows. Please technology stack requirements https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: Check your server log

Comment: See for any information in the server log which can be useful

Comment: Thank you for help me...

Comment: I find-out the mistake : i not set the access permission to package like chmod -R 777 ./

Comment: Now successfully Run the installation step.
Thanks.